# website with huge inline styles

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Recently, I have noticed lots of websites with cool animation/effects but when I tried to dig in, I noticed huge inline styles on elements. Is it because they are using some js plugins to produce those animations?

example sites:
https://la24.org/vision/3

I would appreciate if someone can explore and provide some hints.

thanks

Comment: which element you are referring?Can you please point it from DOM?

Comment: If the answer was useful consider picking it the right answer pls.

Answer (score 2):

It's usual JS animation.

JS doesn't have access to your css file (You can't modify remotely stored file with it). 
But JS does have access to DOM, so for the purpose of dynamic change of css we are writing new style with inline style inside element (Also inline has more weight in CSS). It's completely OK and nothing wrong with it.

More reading on CSS vs JS animation on below:

https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation

And yes, most of websites nowadays use libraries like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) that provide rich API's and timeline for controlling animations.